# Custom listview control for windows mobile in c#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to develop a custom listview control (ie, i need two labels and a progress bar in each list item) . I am new to windows mobile so please help me with code samples.

Comment: You should re-phrase this to be less *plzsendtehcodez* and more *this is what I've tried, how can I get to my end goal*.

Answer (score 4):

Customizing the ListView from C# is difficult - bordering on insane in fact.  Your requirements aren't too terrible since you only want to draw (i.e. you don't want a TextBox or other input type control in an item), so it makes it at least somewhat manageable, but it still requires a lot of P/Invoke shenanigans.

Christian Helle has [a decent blog post](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-custom-drawing-in-netcf.html) that covers custom-draw ListViews in the CF that would be a good start if you don't know where to begin.